# How to convert my Arduino setup to a PIC setup?

Tags: lcd, atmega328, eeprom, rtc

I have an arduino setup with LCD, RTC, EEPROM, Reed Switch, AC/DC Buck Converter, 4X4 Keypad.
What PIC IC will let me connect with all these(40 Pins), and yet accept Arduino Code.
I don't want to rewrite the code. I learn Arduino only recently, So shifting to another coding language is near impossible, since am not a coder.

Comment: so, you go to an Arduino site to ask how to not use an Arduino? ... go to a Microsoft website and ask how to stop using Microsoft software ... see how they like your question

Comment: voting to close because the question is not about an Arduino

Comment: There is a [pinguino](https://pinguino.cc) project which allows you to program PIC MCUs on Arduino IDE like an Arduino.

Comment: There are also many [chipKit](https://chipkit.net/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page)-based boards that can be run under the Arduino IDE environment.

Comment: I am the head honcho for for current chipkit designs. It sounds like the MAX32 is what you want. Equivalent to the Mega. The uC32 may have enough pins too which is an uno equivalent. You should check them out. All PIC32 based.

Comment: @jsotola, I think this question is perfectly acceptable for this site. I support expanding beyond Arduino. Very few of the users here, no doubt, are using genuine Arduino boards which give money to Arduino anyway. The goal isn't to have a pure Arduino site, it's to have a site inspired by Arduino which opens up multiple avenues of creativity and productivity.

Comment: And yes, some PIC boards can be programmed like Arduino. Arduino has inspired a lot of progress in the industry as a whole, and literally changed the world of programmable electronics.

Comment: @hindisong.cc, Why do you want to use a PIC anyway? What are you seeking?

Answer (score 4):

The PIC32 has full (or nearly full) support for the Arduino API through the chipKIT project.  If you want to use one of the smaller PIC chips (PIC16 / PIC18 etc) then you're out of luck. There just isn't a freely available C++ compiler for those chips, so the Arduino API can never really be ported to them.

I have, in the past, cobbled together an Arduino-style API layer for a handful of selected PIC18s which uses structs to emulate a couple of the Arduino C++ objects, but it only worked in a very basic way with no function overloading for things like `Serial.print()`.

One of the problems from a low-end user's perspective is that the PIC32 only comes in harder to use TQFP and QFN etc packages in anything larger than 28 pins. That means you can't breadboard without a development board. Fortunately there are some breadboard friendly options in the chipKIT ecosystem, such as the Fubarino series of boards. For more pins though you'd be wanting one of the bigger boards, such as the MAX32 which is in a Mega footprint (but with even more pins).

It's important to note though that the PIC32 is a 3.3V device and, owing to physical differences in the way that some of the internals work, there are incompatibilities in some of the libraries and functionality (such as no "LOW" or "CHANGE" interrupt support, only "RISING" and "FALLING").